# Grails and python integration

Tags: python, grails, monetdb

I have a **Monet database** to which I need to make a query remotely. There's a plugin for **python** which would make easier to make the query, but I'm creating a **grails** application.

So I need to create a Python module to make the query, and somehow integrate it to grails.

Does somebody knows how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't do that.

Grails is written in Groovy, which is a JVM language; which means it can run any Java code. Monet provides [JDBC drivers](http://dev.monetdb.org/downloads/Java/Jul2015/) which should work with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement python to java with http://www.jython.org

Jython is an implementation of the Python language for the Java platform